# Is there (should there be) any difference between native js defaultValue and jQuery prop(defaultValue)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, default-value

I'm a litte confused about native javascript defaultValue functionality. I have understood that the value of the html input must be set and that value is the initial default value.

I wanted to restore a specific input (text) element to its default value when I have this inside a click-event. (Cancel button)

```
//Restore values
var name_person = $(this).find('.nameOfPerson');       

//Attempt 1
name_person.val(name_person.defaultValue);
alert('restored value=' + name_person.val()); //This alerts nothing

//Attempt 2
name_person.val(name_person.prop('defaultValue')); //This alerts the default value
alert('restored value=' + name_person.val());
```

**Why doesn't native defaultValue attribute work when the prop('defaultValue') does?** Shouldn't those essentially be the same? The initial value is set with value="bla bla bla" in the input element.

I got it to work (with jQuery), but I just wonder - am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not work because `name_person` is a jQuery object and jQuery does not have a `defaultValue`. You need to reference the DOM object

```
name_person[0].defaultValue
```

or

```
name_person.get(0).defaultValue
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot! Now I understand why it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

[Default Value in jquery using attr not prop](http://jsfiddle.net/5DMDh/6/)

just try to know some thing  ..sample html

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" value="default"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

JS

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
$("input[type=text]").val(1);
    alert($("input[type=text]").prop("value"));  // it will return 1 
    alert($("input[type=text]").attr("value"));  // it will return default value


    alert($("input[type=text]")[0].defaultValue);  // @epascarello posted return default value



});
```

Comment: Strange that attr("value") doesn't work same as prop("value"). You would expect to get the current value with attr("value") as well.